# scan/fax with text & numbers in black & white - how to improve/cleanup/enhance using Photoshop/GIMP?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, pdf, scanning, grayscale

I do not have a lot of experience with Photoshop or GIMP.  I have a scanned or faxed document of an invoice/receipt that I am trying to submit to get reimbursed.  I was mailed a copy with text that is speckled/grainy.  I scanned the document and submitted it, however they thought a certain dollar amount was $25.75 instead of $26.15.  I was hoping there would be a quick easy way to improve the quality of the document, being that its just 40 cents difference, to resubmit.  Is there a recommended way to easily improve the original from the scan?

[image: scanned numbers]

I tried the Gaussian blur and sharpen although I did not seem to get any improvements in clarity.  I looked at levels but it seems to be pretty contrasting already with either black or white with not much changing when adjusting the gray channel levels.

Edit: I received this document in the mail (snail mail) from the vendor, which looks like a fax from a third party, so I did not have any control over the fax settings.  I thought about asking the vendor to provide or obtain a better copy, but was interested in finding a quick fix.  I scanned the document I was provided at 600 dpi with my own scanner.

I am currently using Photoshop.  Sharpen did not do much at all unless I did Gaussian blur first (maybe because it is already sharp to begin with because it is black and white?).  If I do Gaussian blur first, and then do sharpen, I can get the text to be thicker and darker, but it is still splotchy, and does not have clearly defined contours.

[image: scanned numbers after Gaussian blur then sharpen]

Since it is black and white, it seems like I need to find a way to fill in or darken only the missing white parts within the character contour.  I don't know if something like that exists, maybe something with the magic wand rather than a filter, where it selects based on the outline/geometry/shape, skipping gaps of certain threshold, rather than the color value or something like that.

Comment: Welcome of Graphic Design SE, Have you tried sharpen? Are you using photoshop or gimp?

Comment: The number reminds me of a Captcha... it's probably their OCR soft that made it 25.75 - for me there is no doubt in 26.15. Apart from that, if the original was poor you will not be able to improve much. Did you try to use a higher resolution in your fax protocol?

Comment: I updated the question with more info.  I am using Photoshop and did try sharpen.  Sharpen didn't seem to do anything, unless Gaussian blur was used first.  I think you are probably correct that the OCR made the mistake and maybe a human doesn't even look at the submitted document.  I received the document via snail mail and was not faxed the document.

Comment: .. re-typeset it.

Comment: How would I re-typeset it?  Is there an automatic method to re-typeset?  I am not the original author of the document.  I have Adobe Acrobat Pro, and can do OCR, but it did not change how the document looks.  I am not sure that Adobe Acrobat Pro's OCR is very accurate and have not had good results in the past.

Comment: Sometimes it is simply easier to retype a document than to try and clean up a poor copy.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that this is just an "accident", and not a systematic approach to reduce the amounts to be reimbursed if in doubt? Even if it is tiny amounts, this will add up.

Comment: Some third party may help you in your case. actually I used to use scanfix ver.4 it is only a black and white solution made specially to enhance scanned documents to let it eligible to OCR. now they have ["scanfix express" ver.7](http://www.accusoft.com/scanfixfeatures.htm) and it can enhance a color photos as well as colored documents. the main great feature in it that it can refill the holes and scratches in the characters. the software is great but it is very expensive ... but the demo version can do all what you want except batching process.

Comment: I think that it was just an accident that the company that reimburses doesn't actually look at the receipts closely or uses OCR or something like that.  I don't think that it is a systematic approach to reduce the amounts reimbursed since I get a notification when the amount I request is not the same as amount paid.  I ended up creating several copies of the document with each one zoomed in more and more on the amounts, so it was easier to see, which ended up being accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation for ScanFix Xpress, I have not heard of it before. It looks like the ScanFix Xpress Character Enhancement would work here on the black and white scan "Repairs, smoothes, and thickens incomplete characters on 1-bit images", "fix jagged dot-matrix text", "smooth ragged edges to improve OCR accuracy"